# Multiple SSL for multiple domains in the same IP

Tags: iis-7, ip, ssl-certificate

We have hosted two domains in the same IP. For example:

- www.domain1.com
- www.domain2.com

Both are hosted in IIS7. We bought the two SSL certificates for each, one for domain1 and other for domain2. I have tried SSL host header to use different SSL for these two domains but it failed. How can i use these two SSL certificates for the respective domains that both are hosted in same IP?

Could anyone please let me know the right way to do this?

Regards,
Karthik.

Comment: This blog post may help someone else with a similar issue. http://blog.armgasys.com/?p=80

Answer (score 4):

By reviewing your requirement, i would suggest two different options:

**Option 1:**
Host both domains on separate IP address. Each SSL needs dedicated IP address to work. You need to pay monthly cost for each IP address.

**Option 2:**
Buy SAN (Subject Alternative Name) SSL certificate. With SAN SSL you can add many domain names in single ssl certificate. Single SSL needs single IP address to work on web-server.

SAN ssl certificates are costly compare to standard ssl certificates.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [SNI (Server Name Indication)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), and it is not supported on IIS7. There is no way to do it.